# List display columns based on ContentType

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, content-type

So I have 2 Folder ContentTypes (*Client Folder* and *Project Folder*).  Client folder can only contain Project Folders, and Documents are added to Project Folders.  Each Document (in Project Folders) has a combo box to determine the type.

So my quandary is such: I only want to show Name and Description for Client Folder.  I want to show Name, Job Number, Approved, and who approved it.  Then inside the Project Folder, show a bunch of fields for each document (like Last Modified, Modified by, Approved, Approved By).  Most importantly, *only* those fields.

I'm coming here as a last resort because I'm stuck and only have been doing SP for the last few months.  I have not found any XSLT files for editing lists to base a new one off of, don't understand how to change STP files, and not really sure where to start.  I've burned through alot of links on MSDN that don't spell things out for my meager understanding.

I do have Sharepoint Designer 2013, VS2013 installed on a Sharepoint 2013 server, and have Word 2013 and Infopath 2013 installed as far as tools go.  Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Pre-Location Settings. Pre-Location Settings are used as per folder. Kindly go through this blog which very goodly show as per your requirement.
http://blog.vossers.com/2009/12/27/per-location-view-settings-in-sharepoint-2010-views-per-content-type/

Google more on it.

Comment: Though if I searched for "Per-Location Settings" instead of "Pre-Location Settings" I'd have less of a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Document Sets?  These will allow you to define a specific view for use within the document set.  They also allow you to specify any metadata you would like the contained documents to inherit.